# csv file that have some rows on two lines

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have a large csv file with columns

```
id,name,sex,ethnicity,hometown,organization,id_card_num,address,mobile_num,phone_num,education
```

The problem is the organization column which is enclosed by double quotes and on *some* rows are split into two lines with a \n newline. I need to join only the lines that match this condition.

Answer (score 8):

Since you tagged [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), the [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module handles newlines in data well.

```perl
#! perl
use Text::CSV;
use autodie;

my $file = shift @ARGV;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1});
open my $fh, "<", $file;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    $row->[2] =~ s/\n/ /g;
    $csv->say(*STDOUT, $row);
}
close $fh;
```

with `file.csv` as

```
ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,AGE
hello,hello,"some ""text"" goes here",1
something,anything,"and now a long
text split over two lines",2
stuff,otherstuff,"something between quotes",3
something,anything,"and now another long text
split over two lines or
even three in this case",4
stuff,stuff,"now I'm done",5
```

`perl joiner.pl file.csv` outputs

```
ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,AGE
hello,hello,"some ""text"" goes here",1
something,anything,"and now a long text split over two lines",2
stuff,otherstuff,"something between quotes",3
something,anything,"and now another long text split over two lines or even three in this case",4
stuff,stuff,"now I'm done",5
```

---

If you want to remove newlines from all fields, not just the specified one, change the first line of the loop to:

```perl
    s/\n/ /g for @$row;
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` should provide another option for you. Though I'm still a bit unclear on how many fields you could have split over multiple lines, and whether your heading line can be split, but counting you have 11-fields in your csv file. (you can add a new first rule of `FNR == 1 { fieldcnt = NF }` to set `fieldcnt` to the number of fields contained in the header and then use that instead of the hardcoded `11` befow). And presuming you don't have additional commas embedded in your quoted fields, you could do something similar to:

```
awk -F, '
    part { 
        part = (part+NF<11) ? part+NF : 0
        if (part)
            partial = partial " " $0
        else
            print partial, $0
        next
    }
    NF < 11 { sub (/\n/,""); partial = $0; part = NF; next } 
    { print }
'  large.csv
```

Above you have three-rules. The first conditions on whether the `part` line variable holds a number greater than zero that tracks the field count. If less than the total, that rule updates `part` by adding the number of fields in the record, and if the total is reached `part` is reset to zero. After updating part, if more is to be read, the `partial` string is appended to, otherwise the `partial` lines are printed along with the current record. Control skips to the `next` record. (it loops until the total field count is reached regardless of the number of lines)

The next rule is conditioned on `NF < 11` (less than the total). If so, the record is assigned to the `partial` string variable, `part` is set to the number of fields in the partial record and control skips to the next record triggering the loop above.

For the last rule, if all fields are present in the record, the record is simply printed with `{ print }`.

If you header record can't be split across lines, then just add the additional rule mentioned above to automatically set the expected number of fields in the `fieldcnt` variable, e.g.

```
awk -F, '
    FNR == 1 { fieldcnt = NF }
    part { 
        part = (part+NF<fieldcnt) ? part+NF : 0
        if (part)
            partial = partial " " $0
        else
            print partial, $0
        next
    }
    NF < fieldcnt { sub (/\n/,""); partial = $0; part = NF; next } 
    { print }
'  large.csv
```

Give it a try. If you have further embedded commas in your quoted field -- **then this method won't work**

**Test Input File**

```
$ cat large.csv
id,name,sex,ethnicity,hometown,organization,id_card_num,address,mobile_num,phone_num,education
10,Minnie,no,furry,Orlando,"Disney World",200,111 Looney Tunes Way,555-1213,555-1214,CartoonU
20,Mickey,yes,furry,Orlando,"Disney
World",201,111 Looney Tunes Way,201,555-1212,555-1211,CartoonU
```

**Example Output**

```
id,name,sex,ethnicity,hometown,organization,id_card_num,address,mobile_num,phone_num,education
10,Minnie,no,furry,Orlando,"Disney World",200,111 Looney Tunes Way,555-1213,555-1214,CartoonU
20,Mickey,yes,furry,Orlando,"Disney World",201,111 Looney Tunes Way,555-1212,555-1211,CartoonU
```

Answer (score 0):

My test file:

```
> cat test.txt 
hello,hello,"some text goes here"
something,anything,"and now a long
text split over two lines"
stuff,otherstuff,"something between quotes"
something,anything,"and now another long text
split over two lines or
even three in this case"
stuff,stuff,"now I'm done"
```

A solution:

```
> cat test.txt  | tr '\n' '#' | sed  's/"#/\n/g' | sed '-e s/$/"/g' -e 's/#/ /'
hello,hello,"some text goes here"
something,anything,"and now a long text split over two lines"
stuff,otherstuff,"something between quotes"
something,anything,"and now another long text split over two lines or#even three in this case"
stuff,stuff,"now I'm done"
```

There's certainly a nicer way but it works. Note that I'm assuming that the text doesn't contain any `#` character.